# Why does Rust store i64s captured by a closure as i64*s in the LLVM IR closure environment?

Tags: rust

In this simple example

```
#[inline(never)]
fn apply<F, A, B>(f: F, x: A) -> B
    where F: FnOnce(A) -> B {
    f(x)
}

fn main() {
    let y: i64 = 1;
    let z: i64 = 2;
    let f = |x: i64| x + y + z;
    print!("{}", apply(f, 42));
}
```

the closure passed to `apply` is passed as a LLVM IR `{i64*, i64*}*`:

```
%closure = type { i64*, i64* }
define internal fastcc i64 @apply(%closure* noalias nocapture readonly dereferenceable(16)) unnamed_addr #0 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
entry-block:
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds %closure, %closure* %0, i64 0, i32 1
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds %closure, %closure* %0, i64 0, i32 0
  %3 = load i64*, i64** %2, align 8
  %4 = load i64*, i64** %1, align 8
  %.idx.val.val.i = load i64, i64* %3, align 8, !noalias !1
  %.idx1.val.val.i = load i64, i64* %4, align 8, !noalias !1
  %5 = add i64 %.idx.val.val.i, 42
  %6 = add i64 %5, %.idx1.val.val.i
  ret i64 %6
}
```

(`apply` actually has a more complicated name in the generated LLVM code.)

This causes two loads to get to each of the captured variables. Why isn't `%closure` just `{i64, i64}` (which would make the argument to `apply` `{i64, i64}*`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html) capture by reference by default. You can change that behavior to capture by value by adding the `move` keyword before the parameter list:

```
let f = move |x: i64| x + y + z;
```

This generates much leaner code:

```
define internal fastcc i64 @apply(i64 %.0.0.val, i64 %.0.1.val) unnamed_addr #0 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"8.unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
entry-block:
  %0 = add i64 %.0.0.val, 42
  %1 = add i64 %0, %.0.1.val
  ret i64 %1
}
```

Adding the `move` keyword means that any value that the closure uses will be moved into the closure's environment. In the case of integers, which are `Copy`, it doesn't make much difference, but in the case of other types like `String`, it means that you can't use the `String` anymore in the outer scope after creating the closure. It's an all-or-nothing deal, but you can manually take references to individual variables outside a `move` closure and have the closure use these references instead of the original values to get manual capture-by-reference behavior.

> Can you observe the value vs ref difference somehow in this code?

[If you take the address of the captured variable, you can observe the difference.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b19252c99d81c362a9b91c4f7af75990&version=stable&backtrace=0) Notice how the first and second output lines are the same, and the third is different.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was assuming that since it's as cheap to copy the `i64`s as it is to take a reference to them (if not cheaper) and since you can't mutate the `i64`s Rust would just copy them by value transparently. Can you observe the value vs ref difference somehow in this code?